# Output past values of a variable during simulation

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

During a when statement, I am using an external C function to output in a csv file the current value of a variable.

For example, for a given variable named `dummy`:

```
when time == 1000 then

  to_csv (dummy, "dummy.csv");

end when;
```

This works but only outputs the current value of the variable. Is it possible to sample the values of the variable in previous time steps too?

Comment: BTW: Don't use "when time==1000". The normal way of writing it is "when time>=1000", or using sample.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is only possible to access variables right before the event using `pre(dummy)`. Previous values are only available through (ugly) workarounds, whereas time-steps taken by the solver cannot be accessed at all. All you can do is write/print at the current time and (post-)process the collected information...

Regarding the first comment (as code is nicer here):

```
model SampleCounter
  Real sampleTimes[:] = 0:0.1:1;
  Integer i(start = 1);

algorithm 
  when time > sampleTimes[i] then
    Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print(String(time) + " at i=" + String(i));
    i :=i + 1;
  end when;
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end SampleCounter;
```

Not sure if that is what you need and also not sure if that is very efficient. It is not exactly my field of experience. Probably it helps though...

Comment: Okay. Looks like I can sample by defining a "sample_time" array and sample by doing

when time > sample_time[i] then;
  save dummy;
  i +=1;
end when;

but I cant increase "i" once I defined. Any idea how can I code this?

Answer (score 2):

The code below demonstrates a simple way to store values at a specific time.
You have to specify when the values are written, how many and the sampling interval.

**EDIT**:
Now the code also supports multiple write times.

```
model WriteBuffer

  import Modelica.Units.SI;
  import Modelica.Utilities.Streams.{print, error};

  parameter SI.Time write_times[:] = {5, 7, 10} "Simulation time at which buffer is written";
  parameter Integer buf_size = 3 "Number of values to store in buffer";
  parameter SI.Time interval = 1e-3 "Sampling time for buffer";

  Real u = sin(2*time) "Exemplary variable to sample";
  Real buffer[buf_size](start=zeros(buf_size), each fixed=true);

protected 

  final parameter Integer nwrite = size(write_times, 1);
  Integer i(start=1) "Buffer index";
  Integer n(start=1) "Write time index";

algorithm 

  when time >= write_times[n]-(buf_size-i)*interval then
    buffer[i] := u;
    i := min(i+1, buf_size);
  end when;

  when time >= write_times[n] then
    if i == buf_size then
      i := 1;
      n := min(n+1, nwrite);
      // to_csv( buffer, "dummy.csv");
      // Instead of writing to csv, we simply print the values here
      print("Values at " + String(time));
      for ii in 1:size(buffer, 1) loop
        print(String(buffer[ii]));
      end for;
    else
      error("Buffer not filled, update settings.");
    end if;
  end when;

equation 

  annotation (experiment(StopTime = 11));
end WriteBuffer;
```

This should give you a good starting point. Note that we have to generate a time event for every value in the buffer. A larger buffer will generate more time events and too many events will slow down the simulation considerably.

Also note that we don't use the solver time steps, but a user defined grid interval. Accessing previous values of solver time steps is not possible with pure Modelica code. If that is needed, try the libraries tbeu suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77587120/8725275).

Comment: This is what I want! When I runt this I get Translation Error
[WriteBuffer: 12:3-12:61]: Non-array modification ‘true‘ for array component ‘fixed‘, possibly due to missing ‘each‘.

Comment: With OpenModelica 1.21.0~2-g0bc3d29

Comment: I tested only in Dymola. Seems like OM is lacking support for some Modelica features. I modified the code, now it also works in OpenModelica (tested with v1.20.0).

Comment: Great!! Last modification, is it possible to make it work for several write_time? E.g. write_time[3] = {1,2,3}. A for loop at the when statement produces an error:  A when-statement may not be used inside a function or a while, if, or for-clause.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [ExternalMemoryLib](https://github.com/vwaurich/ExternalMemoryLib)? Also [LastLib](https://github.com/beutlich/LastLib) can be used to access the value of the previous **valid** simulation step.